# XML Rendering Failed

Tags: android, xml

I'm using Android Studio 2.3 Beta 1, and I'm unable to render the XML file, which makes it unable to work on design.

I've used the following XML code to integrate a profile detail view in my application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              tools:context=".activities.accounts.LoginActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/upperHalf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        <!--android:layout_height="96dp"-->
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:transitionName="upperHalf">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_default_user"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_user"
            app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
            app:civ_border_width="1px" />

    </RelativeLayout>

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/upperHalf">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:background="@android:color/white"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
           android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
           android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/firstName"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/mdtp_material_button_height"
                   android:hint="First Name" />

           </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/lastName"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/mdtp_material_button_height"
                   android:hint="Last Name" />

           </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="14dp"
               android:text="Gender"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:textSize="12sp"
               android:textColor="@color/darkGrayTextColor"/>

           <Spinner
               android:id="@+id/spinnerGender"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="34dp"
               android:textColor="@android:color/white"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:background="@drawable/boder_bottom"/>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="14dp"
               android:text="Country"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:textSize="12sp"
               android:textColor="@color/darkGrayTextColor"/>

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/btnCountry"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="34dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:text="@string/select_country"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:textAlignment="gravity"
               android:gravity="center_vertical"
               android:background="@drawable/boder_bottom"/>


           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/localization"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/mdtp_material_button_height"
                   android:hint="Localization"/>

           </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/dateOfBirth"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/mdtp_material_button_height"
                   android:hint="Date of Birth"
                   android:focusable="false"
                   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                   android:inputType="none"/>
           </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="@dimen/mdtp_material_button_height"
               android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:text="Is Profile Public" />

               <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                   android:id="@+id/switchPublic"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
           </RelativeLayout>

       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I have attached the error from Android Studio.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TextAppearance
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelper.java:88)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelperV17.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatTextHelperV17.java:38)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:67)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:441)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:240)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:195)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(CustomBar.java:95)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(StatusBar.java:67)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createStatusBar(Layout.java:224)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:146)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:301)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: i guess it's probably is showing during XML design , try changing the theme in design layout , clear and rebuild also work most of the time and make sure no resource is missing if you using some resource

Comment: can you share the xml code ?

Comment: tried doing that. It didnt help :(.

Comment: Your layout looks like this when I pasted your code in my Android studio, Have a look:- http://prntscr.com/dorbtp, and You have not given height in upperHalf layout

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any custom text designs? SuchFieldError: TextAppearence suggests this might be the case.

Comment: No I have not used as you can check my xml.

Comment: Have you applied any global text appearance change in your theme or manifest?